# JavaFX load intensive application design

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, javafx

I'm writing an application in Java 8 with an HMI and a logical part. The logic is consuming a lot of cpu power and for now it's situated in an own jvm. The HMI makes use of javafx and is running in a separate jvm as well. The two jvms communicate with each other over sockets. So far, so good. As it makes things quite complicated with separate jvms it would be very nice to fuse them. Although I'm familiar with the fx application thread and worker threads, I really don't know if it is a good idea to have these two applications in one jvm. First of all, the logical part needs the highest priority possible. If the HMI freezes for a second - we can live with that. But garbage collection of gui elements can probably cause the logical part to be interrupted. We cannot live with that. We also observed with the current implementation that javafx animations cause the logical jvm to be interrupted (maybe these are just taskswitches or it's something related to the scheduler).

In short:

- HMI in one jvm
- Logic in other jvm

Idea:

- Fuse HMI and Logic in one jvm with worker threads/services/task

Issues:

- JavaFx animations interrupt logical jvm

Concerns (assuming HMI and logic in one jvm):

- Garbage collection of HMI - stop the world - logical part gets interrupted
- Priority of background threads (woker/service/task) must be higher than fx thread

Has anybody concerns or hints on how to best solve such an issue?

Comment: Why fuse them if it works in separated jvm ??

Comment: @user43968 because the communication is pretty complicated and it would be much easier to just have access to certain objects. Further we observed, that the Garbage Collection of the RMI objects (which is caused by the rmi java lib) is interrupting the logical part too much.